# itext7.pdfhtml is ignoring padding and new lines when single file published

Tags: c#, .net-core, itext7, pdfhtml

I have noticed that itext7.pdfhtml is generating incorrect PDF when app is published with PublishSingleFile set to true. Am I doing something wrong or is this known behavior?

This

```
C:\Projects\itext7test\itext7test\>dotnet publish --self-contained -r win-x64 -c Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.0+41abc5629 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  itext7test -> C:\Projects\itext7test\itext7test\bin\Release\net6.0\win-x64\itext7test.dll
  itext7test -> C:\Projects\itext7test\itext7test\bin\Release\net6.0\win-x64\publish\
C:\Projects\itext7test\itext7test\>.\bin\Release\net6.0\win-x64\publish\itext7test.exe
```

generates correct PDF (preview https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUSJc.png).

and this

```
C:\Projects\itext7test\itext7test\>dotnet publish --self-contained -r win-x64 -c Release -p:PublishSingleFile=true
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.0+41abc5629 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  itext7test -> C:\Projects\itext7test\itext7test\bin\Release\net6.0\win-x64\itext7test.dll
  itext7test -> C:\Projects\itext7test\itext7test\bin\Release\net6.0\win-x64\publish\
C:\Projects\itext7test\itext7test\>.\bin\Release\net6.0\win-x64\publish\itext7test.exe
```

generates incorrect PDF where all `<br/>` tags and paddings are ignored (preview https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvINf.png).

Program.cs:

```cs
using iText.Html2pdf;
using iText.Html2pdf.Resolver.Font;

var pdfStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("out.pdf");

var converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
var fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, true);
converterProperties.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);

var generatedHtml = $@"<html lang=""cs"">
    <head>
<meta charset=""UTF-8""/>
<title></title>
<style>
    body, div, p {{padding: 10px;line-height: 1.75em;}}
    body {{font-family: Arial, sans-serif;}}
    div {{border: 1px solid black;}}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style=""page-break-after: always;"">
        <div>
            <p style=""width: 40%;display: inline-block"">
                firma<br/>
                adresa<br/>
                zipcode city<br/>
                IČO: 123456789<br/>
            </p>
            <p style=""width: 40%;display: inline-block;text-align: right;float: right"">
                Příjmový pokladní doklad<br/>
                Číslo: <b>0</b><br/>
                Ze dne: <b>{DateTime.Now:d.M.yyyy}</b><br/>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            Celková částka: <b> Kč</b><br/>
            Slovy: <b>~~ korun českých~~</b><br/>
            Účel platby: <br/>
        </div>
        <div>
            Přijato od: <br/>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div>
            Přijal:<br/>&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>";

HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(generatedHtml, pdfStream, converterProperties);
```

itext7test.csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="itext7.pdfhtml" Version="4.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Dotnet info:

```
c:\>dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.302
 Commit:    c857713418

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19044
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.7
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       0ec02c8c96

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.409 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

Comment: Just tried to install newest .net 6 SDK 6.0.400 and it still behaves same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some circumstances iText currently has an issue with parsing the default CSS file that is embedded into pdfHTML distribution. It's an analogue of default CSS that many browsers have.

What you can do as a workaround is:

1. Download the `default.css` from the pdfHTML repository (https://github.com/itext/i7n-pdfhtml/blob/master/itext/itext.html2pdf/resources/default.css).
2. Put the downloaded file into your working directory
3. Add the link to the CSS file from your HTML: `<link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""default.css""/>`

You can also put your `default.css` to another directory and either refer to the file at the absolute path or tweak `converterProperties.SetBaseUri()` so that the base directory (the one that the `default.css` file will be resolved against) differs from your work directory.

You can also integrate this CSS in a different way, for instance by copy-pasting the content and embedding it into your HTML. The main point is to get this CSS picked up.